# Ember project to Github Pages

Tags: javascript, web, ember.js, deployment, web-deployment

I just finished making an ember project (super simple nothing huge)
You can check it out <[here](https://github.com/Jxa3128/MyPhotoBlog)>

but I am trying to deploy it to make it into a website on github pages and there is hardly any documentation out there and was wondering if I could get some help. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are three strategies to do so these days:

1. [Ember CLI Deploy](http://ember-cli-deploy.com/) is a famous deployment pipeline for Ember.js applications. The [ember-cli-deploy-git](https://github.com/ef4/ember-cli-deploy-git) plugin adds support for GitHub Pages as deployment target. There is an additional plugin [ember-cli-deploy-git-ci](https://github.com/dfreeman/ember-cli-deploy-git-ci), which adds support for deployments from a CI pipeline on top of that one.
2. The Ember addon [ember-cli-github-pages](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-github-pages) adds a command to Ember CLI, which deploys the project to GitHub Pages. It's similar to the Ember CLI Deploy pipeline but working as a standalone solution.
3. You can deploy to GitHub Pages from [GitHub actions](https://github.com/features/actions). There are different Actions available in GitHub Marketplace to do so. The most famous one if comparing by stars is the [GitHub Pages action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-pages-action). To use it you would need to build your Ember project as usual and set the `publish_dir` option of the action to `./dist`. Ember CLI stores the build output by default in that folder.

It's up to you which approach you use. All of them are common in the ecosystem. Maybe some hints to decide:

- If running the CI on GitHub actions, I would recommend to also us it for deployment.
- If using Ember CLI Deploy in that project already for deployment to another environment, I would recommend to use it for deployments to GitHub Pages as well.
- If not using a CI at all and just looking for a quick solution, I would go with `ember-cli-github-pages` as this is the simplest one.
- If this is a playground project and you want to learn more about the common deployment process for Ember applications, I would go with Ember CLI Deploy.